# CHKDSK Error while trying to repair External Drive: A disk read error occurredc0000010

Tags: windows, hard-drive, data-recovery

I am having issues accessing a External Drive. I used CHKDSK but, I get the following result. Can anyone please help me. I have accepted that this HDD is failing, but I really need to back my data up.

```
C:\Windows\system32>chkdsk H: /f /r
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is Gurmukh Singh.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0x80, "")
from file record segment 0x98CC.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0x80, "")
from file record segment 0x9C37.
  107776 file records processed.
File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 1.85 seconds.
  2 large file records processed.
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00 milliseconds.
  0 bad file records processed.
 Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 0.77 milliseconds.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
A disk read error occurredc0000010
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 5.
CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the bitmap for index $I30 for file 5.
Sorting index $I30 in file 5.
  6733 reparse records processed.
Inserting an index entry into index $O of file 19.
  120196 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
 Phase duration (Index verification): 3.20 minutes.
CHKDSK is scanning unindexed files for reconnect to their original directory.
Recovering orphaned file DOWNLO~1.MKV (1AC3) into directory file 5.
Recovering orphaned file Downloadhub.in.mkv (1AC3) into directory file 5.
Recovering orphaned file NEWMOV~1 (4F0F) into directory file 5.
Recovering orphaned file New Movies (4F0F) into directory file 5.
Recovering orphaned file SYSTEM~1 (7768) into directory file 5.
Recovering orphaned file System Volume Information (7768) into directory file 5.
Recovering orphaned file Darsh (85B8) into directory file 5.
Recovering orphaned file VLC (957E) into directory file 5.
Recovering orphaned file GDPR_M~1.XLS (98D0) into directory file 5.
Recovering orphaned file GDPR_MarkCold_V1.0.xlsm (98D0) into directory file 5.
Skipping further messages about recovering orphans.
  17 unindexed files scanned.
  14 unindexed files recovered to original directory.
 Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 0.00 milliseconds.
CHKDSK is recovering remaining unindexed files.
  3 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
    Lost and found is located at \found.000

 Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 0.00 milliseconds.
  6733 reparse records processed.
 Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 50.61 milliseconds.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
 Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 66.60 milliseconds.
Inserting data attribute into file 98CC.
Inserting data attribute into file 9C37.
  6213 data files processed.
 Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 2.08 milliseconds.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
A disk read error occurredc0000010
Insufficient disk space to fix the Usn Journal $J data stream.
```

Comment: Try EaseUS, Recuva and software like that. Consider (before using software apps) a local recovery agency.

Comment: The time to back up your data is *before* the drive fails. What you're now into is *recovery*. You have two issues, 1) the drive is failing & 2) it's too full for chkdisk to finish the repair. Repeated use of chkdsk is very likely to just lose more data each time - its job is to fix the filesystem, it doesn't care one bit for your data. You need a second, larger drive & as John says, recovery software or a recovery company.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1765446/705502

Answer (score 1):

The operation of `chkdsk /f` is very dangerous, since if the disk is
broken enough, chkdsk can when fixing bad data also destroy good data.

My advice :

- Do not modify anything any more on this disk !
- If you don't have backups for the disk, save now everything that
  you can still access
- For unrecovered data, you could try free recovery programs such as
  [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva)
  or its many
  [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/recuva/)
  (beware of bundleware)
- If important data is still unrecovered, use a professional
  data recovery company (costly)
- If all data has been recovered and you wish to try and reuse the disk,
  full-format it and verify its SMART status before using it
  (if it supports SMART). If this comes up with many bad sectors,
  the disk should be junked.

Comment: It's very unlikely an external enclosure over USB will support SMART. Rest I am with you all the way. I did wonder about `dd` to a larger drive, but idk how you would deal with enlarging the copied volume without potentially upsetting existing data.

Comment: Many modern USB enclosures pass on SMART commands and most SMART tools can send passthrough commands. All the ones I got past 2 years support SMART.